# Getting Windows 8 to go back to Metro Start Screen after closing a program started from desktop

Tags: windows, windows-8, start-screen

I would like to have Windows 8 automatically go back to the Metro Start Screen when I close a program or file as opposed to going back to desktop.

How can this be done?

Comment: This might not be exactly what you want(as even pressing a button isn't an option) but you can drag down desktop after closing the window just like any other metro UI app.

Comment: Is it so hard to press "Windows" key after closing any program ?)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com). Install it, and create following 2 files:

**switcher.ahk**

```
#SingleInstance force

WinGet, id_ini, list,,, Program Manager
prev = %id_ini%

loop 
{
sleep 3000     ; Milliseconds for which the loop waits before another iteration
WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager
current = %id%
if(current < prev)
{
  ;somethin closed - press windows key here
  Run, "C:\press_windows.vbs"   
}
prev = %id%
sleep 500
}
```

**press_windows.vbs**

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^{ESCAPE}"
```

**After creating both files** and adjusting the Path in the **switcher.ahk** file to the location of vbs you created. You just need to **Run** the Autohotkey file (*i.e. switcher.ahk*) and you are done.

This will count all windows (Excluding the Background Services and Processes)
And If number of Windows Reduces it sends a Windows key press and switches to Modern-UI.

*I'm using a VBS because for some reason Windows-8 doesn't take a Windows Key press from AHK.*

**Note:** This script needs to be refined, sometimes it may behave unexpectedly, because it also counts the Context Menu and Notifications as new window. So when they are closed it sends a keypress.
To avoid such behavior we need to exclude such things, which can be done easily.

Comment: How does this improve over pressing WinKey?  I am looking for an automatic return to the Metro UI

Comment: Using this you **don't** need to press WinKey. Isn't this an Improvement ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a VBS script file and use it to launch your target application, the following instructions will do as you require:

```
'// File:  app2metro.vbs
'// Desc:  launch notepad then return to the metro interface

'//create shell object
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'// run and wait for it to return
intReturn = WshShell.Run("notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, TRUE)

'//switch to metro 
WshShell.SendKeys "^{ESCAPE}"
```

Comment: Interesting, but I would have to script each application?

Comment: Yes. Each app that you would want to auto return to metro. I'm unaware of any other approach that would work for arbitrary applications.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not hard at all to press the "Windows" key after closing a program, it would make sense that if you start a program from the Metro Start Screen, you return to it afterwards. Especially if that is what you want to promote.